# Getting the reference of the elements with and without using the Form References in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, forms

Problem Statement:

I have a DOM structure in which there are two forms objects present under different parents. The form objects share the same ID. Each form object has two elements in it with different values.

Base Page:

ParentA (id=ParentA) --> FormA  (id=FormA) --> RadioOne (id=RadioOne) value=false, RadioTwo doesn't exist.

Popup:

ParentB (id=ParentB) --> FormA  (id=FormA) --> RadioTwo (id=RadioTwo) value=true, RadioOne doesn't exist.

The reason for structure is because the ParentB is a popup which opens the same form with different values over a base page which has ParentA in it. The popup is a JqueryColorBox and just before closing the popup I want to grab the values of the elements on the Base Page (which happen to have the same IDs).

After the popup has been displayed, now in my javascript file, I am trying following:

var radioOne = $("#RadioOne");   //This results in radioOne object with value false
var radioTwo = $("#RadioTwo");    //This results in radioTwo object with value true

Since I am interested in knowing the values of the elements in the Base Page, if I try the following and this is what I expect it to return:

var $parentForm = $("#FormA");    //Not sure which FormA instance is returned here

var radioOne = $parentForm.find("#RadioOne);  //This results in radioOne as false.
var radioTwo = $parentForm.find("#RadioTwo);  //This results in radioTwo as undefined.

Problem:

Basically, I am interested in knowing the values of the elements in the Base Page and not the ones present on the popup.  If I do not use the form reference and use the jquery selector, I am given the RadioOne value from the Base Page and the RadioTwo value is provided from the popup.

On using the form reference, I am able to get the values from the Base Page but I am not sure if this is the right approach because I am not positive if the Form Reference is returned correctly. Both the Base Page FormA and the popup FormA share the same ID.

Is there a better way to obtain the element values form the Base Page without using the form reference?

Comment: I got as far as "share the same ID", error, did not compute. You can't have the same ID on multiple elements !

Comment: @adeneo - i know this rule of thumb, but the popup happens to be using the same JSP which has the elements with matching IDs as the one loaded on the base page. In order to reuse the underlying JSP, the elements which are on the popup share the same IDs as the base page elements. But for me, the scripts doesn't stop with any fatal error.

Comment: @sunsin1985 it's not a "rule of thumb", it's a full-on **rule**.  Things just won't work if you re-use "id" values.

Comment: @pointy - so to handle this problem should I regenerate the IDs of all the elements declared in the server side JSP if the JSP is compiled to an HTML when it it rendered on the popup and when it is rendered on the base page?

Comment: @sunsin1985 yes - fix your JSP code so that it creates unique "id" values every time it's used on a page.  Or, don't use "id" values at all - use classes.